# Inferring the argument of one function based on the return value of another

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a generic calculator for various statistics of an input dataset. Consider the following existing code:

```js
type InputData = {
  foo: number[];
  bar: number[];
  baz: {
    qux: number;
  };
};

const input: InputData = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3],
  bar: [4, 5, 6],
  baz: {
    qux: 5,
  },
};

type StatisticDefinition = {
  name: string;
  mapper: (input: InputData) => unknown;
  calculator: (mappedValue: unknown) => unknown;
};

type StatisticDefinitions = {
  [key: string]: StatisticDefinition;
};

const statisticDefinitions: StatisticDefinitions = {
  averageFoo: {
    name: "Average Foo",
    mapper: (input) => input.foo,
    calculator: (mappedValue) => {
      const foo = mappedValue as number[];
      return foo.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / foo.length;
    },
  },
  barPlusQux: {
    name: "Bar Plus Qux",
    mapper: (input) => [input.bar, input.baz.qux],
    calculator: (mappedValue) => {
      const [bar, qux] = mappedValue as [number[], number];
      return bar.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + qux;
    },
  },
};

for (const [key, statisticDefinition] of Object.entries(statisticDefinitions)) {
  const mappedValue = statisticDefinition.mapper(input);
  const calculatedValue = statisticDefinition.calculator(mappedValue);
  console.log(`${key} (${statisticDefinition.name}): ${calculatedValue}`);
}
```

([TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAIgQ2GqBeKBvAKCigDMB7MgLijkQFsAjCAJwG0BdAbiKgbWeq1GLDt2J8AXtULFiAR0QAPQfSbMxUAL7dtBAgGMycAM7AoASwTJq8JKgxZcM0hWqsAjABooAJm8Bmdk8ePgEoVgAWbwBWbwA2IJC0KXweeSVqWJ5NYN0CUEgoAGVMYHNTc30UCBJLczKjHFTiODQ6CGpTZksAcw06NDBIMIAKSzsbK3tMAEocAD4oRDgAazgyAHc4DX00ABt9RD2MMlGBoYgAEwA1fcQOpdX1rbnsReW1ze2CPILoEow5TKVRqdQaJiazlYKwgIE6wG6cB67GoALKFRBtTg9XMRh03AMRlMUFMgIx1SxOKJqNKQMqFLBuIhTh4aAAbiw0D0IAAxVzNWStdrUABEAEEOcwudA%20WQRcFZFBzsNqGMpq9FuNkAA6chkBWyXYHI4nM6DSA3O4QDUCxWGExmPVNZVXW57e5QNDGGiqERcNKyZgQYCIZhwFxkbVBy6IfQQEYjNDeBg2rAAal43gADHMAPQR7V7CBI4AACw0xBy2QNoQACu7jABFDK2mhtB4igBC-Cg9cQ3ubinlAZdoy1wBtrHH2tC3mnkm1CkUiTt%200Ox2Ap1VLst7utC1bxHtxNYs6gS-YzvNrqtnu9rCEag43kfLH9iuIQZDYd4-CjV1jeNE2TVMoAzBhszmDMlwrLQDSrPJyGYKARmPMxoVhbxSXRYEGWxcFLzIEgoAAeQYAArCB9GAbViwRcwIGMEZsLpTFGSJGY5mcNClWvXcPVwFjyVBfCmW1Uc1TsGYdiJMwjXXDAbz3JohNwkSqTgbV5JNTdmBGHc3XuaSeGPMgi0LMgehGAADAASPAYRATQUPs1T6XU8FtSFCBNBmah7O0jclPuTRrOMzQCCAA))

As you can see, it runs correctly, and in my list of statistic definitions, I can add as many as I want. The `mapper` determines the inputs for the `calculator` function, but at the moment, both the return type of the mapper as well as the input type of the calculator function are `unknown`, and I have to use `as` to coerce the type based on what I know from the mapper's return value.

Is there any way to automatically infer the argument type of the `calculator` function based on what `mapper` returns?

Since everything is defined in one object, that may not be possible, but it does not necessarily have to be this way — it could also be structured inside a class, if necessary. I just need a concise way (a sort of DSL) to define the various statistics.

Comment: The only way this could work is if you make `StatisticDefinition` generic in the type of the mapper output (not `unknown`). But getting an object full of these to infer properly is probably impossible (see [ms/TS#47599](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) and [ms/TS#30134](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134)) so you'd need a helper function as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/w1EKlw). (Note that I asserted to make the iteration work, as that's mostly outside the scope of the q.) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Interesting! That definitely works. Please post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the compiler to keep track of the return type of `mapper` so that it knows the input type of `calculator`, then you will need to make `StatisticDefinition` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type `T`.  You might also want the compiler to keep track of the return type `R` of `calculator`, so we can make it generic in that too:

```
type StatisticDefinition<T, R> = {
  name: string;
  mapper: (input: InputData) => T;
  calculator: (mappedValue: T) => R;
};
```

So your `statisticDefinitions` will be of a type like

```
declare const statisticDefinitions: {
    averageFoo: StatisticDefinition<number[], number>;
    barPlusQux: StatisticDefinition<[number[], number], number>;
};
```

but presumably you don't want to have to *annotate* that.  It would be great if we could ask the compiler to just infer the type for us, but there's no direct way to do that.  Instead we can make a generic helper function which infers the type arguments for you.  I couldn't get this to work as-desired on the full object, since that would need to be a generic [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like

```
type StatisticDefinitions<T = any, R extends Record<keyof T, any> = any> = 
  { [K in keyof T]: StatisticDefinition<T[K], R[K]> }
```

and the inference doesn't work well.  (It's a general limitation of TypeScript's generic-plus-[contextual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) inference, described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) and [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134); without a complete refactor there will always be situations where TypeScript's type inference doesn't succeed where it technically could.)

Instead we can write this helper function to be called once for each `StatisticDefinition<T, R>` property:

```
const asStatisticDefinition = <T, R>(sd: StatisticDefinition<T, R>) => sd;
```

Like this:

```
const statisticDefinitions = {
  averageFoo: asStatisticDefinition({
    name: "Average Foo",
    mapper: (input) => input.foo,
    calculator: (mappedValue) => {
      return mappedValue.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / mappedValue.length;
    },
  }),
  barPlusQux: asStatisticDefinition({
    name: "Bar Plus Qux",
    mapper: (input) => [input.bar, input.baz.qux] as const,
    calculator: (mappedValue) => {
      const [bar, qux] = mappedValue;
      return bar.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + qux;
    },
  }),
};
```

That works as intended.  The compiler knows that `averageFoo.calculator`'s input is of type `number[]`, while `barPlusQux,calculator`'s input is of type `readonly [number[], number]` (note that I had to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the `barPlusQux.mapper` return value, because you want the compiler to understand that it's a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of one `number[]` element and one `number` element, instead of just an unordered arbitrary-length array of type `Array<number[] | number>`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAIgQ2GqBeKBvAKCigDMB7MgLijkQFsAjCAJwG0BdAbiKgbWeq1GLDt2J8AXtULFiAR0QAPQfSbMxUAL7dtBAgGMycAM7AoASwTJq8JKgxZcM0hWqsAjABooAJm8Bmdk8ePgEoVgAWbwBWbwA2IJC0KXweeSVqWJ5NYN0CUEgoAGVMYHNTc30UCBJLczKjAB4AFW8AJQA+HFTiODQ6CGpTZksAcw06NDBIMIAKSzsbK3tMAEocLuaNfTQAG31EXYwyOcnpiAATADU9xEGoZvXsLradbgMjUyg0YxKMcrKVRqdQacG6LXaHVmxgu1D+ZQqQNqcHq5iarSgnSeXRh7z0hhMZlM-0R1WRqM+3WcaAAbiw0KMIAAxVzfX6lAGVMkgtFwWbOXr9e4AIgAgnTmAzoCyyMLgrIoGcZtR5stsRZlgA6chkeWyHb7Q7HU5TSDXW4QdUC2TMCDARDMMFKy43XZ3TW2i6IfQQWazNDeBjqrAAal43gADOsAPSK00ui2a3YQOCjYAACw0xBy2VWetCAAU3cYAIoZNnwzlInlGflpGhC6jCgBC-CgRcQxigZcUcvrzrmC2Q6tYQ+AmtC3jHE+SmoUinYbKgBNMeuIBoOR2AJxVzvNbstGx6CuXnzMrEnUHni9we9ddyzNrtDrBoQ9l29vv9geDUDDDEjdYw3nR8c2zPMCDyApoErUlgRRUFjBabo0DgEB2igCBFGAFMLi7NoIEMZgLkaABrCAQDIEgHm8VCQC6XA6IYqACDwcIAGkNSgcjKOo5p2DhDk4PJUEWlYdigkxcT2C6TQ9HIZgoFmFdzx47xiQRQFuQQ3lFyoqAAHkGAAK0I8cU2AEYIGMaEhK0+CKRMJdYPskTeWMVZ1mcFS43Ofc7m6DSq20xzNQHVU7FWbYz2XPZNwwBMD0CuyuQc0FNQ3I1t2YWY7wtKKeBXMhkyTMhRlmAADAASPAeM0JSaqC4SazgTU+gGTRVmoGrMq3RK7k0CqCs0IA)

Comment: This is great, thanks for the additional context.